# Div's with display inline-block display weird (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I worked at a template and i tried to use `display: inline-block;` to arange the divs on page and i observed a behaviour that i couldn't explain.  The div's with `display: inline-block;` containing some element like : `span`, `div` or `a` are displayed below than without something inside.

I looked with Firebug but there is not a margin or padding arround that could explain the spacing.

This behaviour is fix only if i display the `span`, `div` or `a` as :

1. `table-cell` // Chrome Firefox IE9
2. `table-row`    // Chrome Firefox IE9
3. `flex`  // Only Firefox
4. `table`// Chrome Firefox IE9

Can someone provide more details or some advice aboud this behaviour.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bogdan_vq/85StK/4/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to your `div`s like so:

```
div {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Demo in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/85StK/5/

This homogenizes the vertical alignment of the div's making a them all display inline .