# What's the different between <div> and <span> if I set display: block or inline to them?

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="display: inline"></div>
<span></span>

<div></div>
<span style="display:block></span>

<div style="display: inline-block"></div>
<span style="display: inline-block"></span>
```

If I write like this, what's the different between `<div>` and `<span>`

Comment: You're asking about the difference of two HTML elements (data) but argue using CSS (presentation). If the presentation is the same, what's left is the data and **semantics**. Neither `<span>` nor `<div>` have any significant semantic meaning.

Comment: without any display span remains inline but div cuts to the next line

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between HTML tags DIV and SPAN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183532/what-is-the-difference-between-html-tags-div-and-span)

Comment: I didn't know `display` could be set to `line` or `line-block` :P. (Hint, it can't)

Answer (score 5):

In terms of CSS, there is no difference. You can style any element regardless of its semantics however you like.

Likewise, in terms of HTML, how you style them with CSS does not affect their nature. A `<div>` always accepts any flow content, which is *typically* represented as block-level elements in CSS, or phrasing content, which is typically represented as inline elements in CSS. Note however that there isn't a necessary correlation between the two concepts. A `<span>` on the other hand can only have phrasing content.

In valid HTML, this means while a `<div>` can contain a `<span>`, a `<span>` cannot contain a `<div>`.

Both elements are similar in that they carry no semantics by themselves; they simply function as grouping elements for their contents, typically used for styling purposes.

See the HTML5 spec for [`<div>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) and [`<span>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

**div**

- A "block-level element"
- can contain all other elements!
- can only be inside other block-level elements
- defines a rectangular region on the page
- tries to be as wide as possible
- begins on a "new line", and has an "carriage return" at the end, like
  a `<p>`

**span**

- An "inline element"
- cannot contain block-level elements!!
- can be inside any other element
- defines a "snake" on the page
- tries to be as small as possible
- doesn't create any new lines

From a rendering point of view,

```
<span> == <div style="display: inline">
```

and

`<div> == <span style="display: block">`

**As for HTML syntax, however, a `div` cannot be nested inside an `inline` element, whereas a `span` cannot contain block-level elements.**

**The mysterious `"display: inline-block"`**

```
block vs inline vs inline-block
```

Below are a bunch of  with different display: settings.

[image]

As you can see, `inline-block` is a hybrid that:

- Creates a rectangular region (a block)
- Doesn't create any new lines (hence "in line")

For more information

[Div's with display inline-block display weird (CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536597/divs-with-display-inline-block-display-weird-css)

[Difference between DIV as-is and a SPAN with display:block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142104/difference-between-div-as-is-and-a-span-with-displayblock)

http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html

Answer (score 1):

The point is based on the HTML spec, `span` tags are `inline` elements and `div` tags are a `block` element, and these 2 can get changed using `display` rule in CSS.

So if you change the `display` there won't be any difference.

But in terms of the way these are usually used, you can consider `div` to wrap the sections in the DOM and `span` tags mostly are used to wrap texts and contents.

Check the [HTML spec document](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4) out for more info.